# Recoding audio: libav encoder/decoder in gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, codec

I want to recode the audio stream of an audio file. The following gstreamer pipeline works just fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.flac ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! \
               sbcenc ! sbcdec ! autoaudiosink
```

However, when I switch the encoder/decoder to libav aptx, I get the following error:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.flac ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! \
               avenc_aptx ! avdec_aptx ! autoaudiosink
```

I get the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstAudioConvert named audioconvert0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstFlacParse:flacparse0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/libs/gst/base/gstbaseparse.c(3634): gst_base_parse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstFlacParse:flacparse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What am I missing in my pipelines? How can I use the FFMPEG/libav codecs?

I am a gstreamer novice and want to use the cli tools for recoding an audio stream into a bunch of different codecs. libav seems to have all the needed codecs.

Comment: aptx surely isn't AAC.

Comment: you are absolutely right. It was a typo and I fixed it right away. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok with your pipeline but...

Execute `gst-launch-1.0 --version` to check the version of your Gstreamer.

With Gstreamer version 1.15.90 I inspected `avenc_aptx` with `gst-inspect-1.0 avenc_aptx` and found out that this encoder's SRC(source) capabilities are 'unknown'. And Gstreamer elements need capabilities to be shared in order to connect with each other.

On the other side, documentation for [avenc_aptx](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/libav/avenc_aptx.html?gi-language=c) clearly states that there are SRC capabilities (audio/aptx....).

The same situation is for decoder `avdec_aptx` where SINK capabilities are 'unknown' but the documentation clearly mentions SINK capabilities.

So it is very possible that your problem is caused by a fact that your Gstreamer version has partially (incompletely) implemented aptx encoder and decoder.

Try upgrading Gstreamer to the latest version, inspect aptx encoder/decoder again and, if SRC/SINK capabilities are visible, re-run your pipeline.

Comment: I run Arch Linux with Gstreamer version 1.16.2. It's a pity, that the codecs are not yet fully implemented. In the meantime I found a workaround using ffmpeg. However, in the long-run it would be nice to use gstreamer for that...